# What is the ramification locus of $Spec\mathbb{Z}[x]\rightarrow Spec\mathbb{Z}[x]$ given by $x\mapsto x^2$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

$\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb{Z}}$
$\newcommand{\Spec}{\text{Spec }}$
Let $A = B = \ZZ[x]$, and consider the map $B\rightarrow A$ given by $x\mapsto x^2$. Intuitively, $f : \Spec A\rightarrow\Spec B$ should be a degree 2 map ramified exactly where $x = 0$. The ramification locus is also precisely the points $x$ where the stalk of $\Omega_{A/B}$ at $x$ is nonzero.

This means that when $P\in\Spec A$ is the point corresponding to the maximal ideal $(2,x-1)$, then the stalk of $\Omega_{A/B}$ at that point should be zero. How do we see this? By definition, $\Omega_{A/B}$ is the $\ZZ[x]$-module generated by the symbol $dx$, with usual Leibniz relations, together with $dx^2 = 2xdx = 0$. Since $x$ is invertible after localizing at $(2,x-1)$, this last relation gives us $2dx = 0$. However, 2 is not invertible here, so how can we deduce that $dx = 0$?

I'm just trying to work out a baby example of the ramification locus being the support of the sheaf of relative differentials. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Using $x$ both for the variable and for the point in the spectrum of A is a bad idea!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Thanks! I've changed it now.

Comment: I was never good at this, but why wouldn't you get ramification at all the maximal ideals $(2,f(x))$, $f(x)$ irreducible modulo $2$, as well as at the maximal ideals $(p,x)$? Exactly because of the $2x$ factor in $2x\,dx$?

Comment: I guess your problem may be to extrapolate from the case of $\text{Spec}\, K[x]\to \text{Spec}\, K[x]$, with $K$ a field, where $x\mapsto x^2$ gives the usual morphism from the affine line to itself - the only branch cut at the origin (the projective version would also ramify at $\infty$). Here $\text{Spec}\,\Bbb{Z}[x]$ is more like a 2-dimensional object...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen well it's not really the 2-dimensionality that's the problem. The situation of $Spec K[t][x]\rightarrow Spec K[t][x]$ is very similar to the case of $Spec K[x]$ in the sense that the ramification locus is just the $x=  0$ line

Comment: Hmm. I think that here you get the union of two lines: $x=0$ and $p=2$

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting this, but why is $dx^2=0$? It is not from the Leibniz relations, right?

Comment: @neptun $x^2$ comes from the base ring, so it's like a "constant", and for constants $a$, you always have $da = 0$

Comment: @JEFFYELTON, ah, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so Jyrki's right, and the map $f$ is ramified at both $x = 0$, and at $p = 2$. Indeed, the argument in the OP proves that it is certainly unramified when $x \ne 0$ and $p\ne 2$. To see that it's ramified at $p = 2$, we may consider $A\otimes_B B/(2)$ over $B/(2)$, which is just $\mathbb{F}_2(x)$ over $\mathbb{F}_2(x)$ with the map given by $x\mapsto x^2$. Since this is a inseparable field extension, it's ramified. Since the ramification locus is closed, it must include all points over $p = 2$.